# Energy needed for electrolysis of aqueous NaBr

Tags: energy, electrolysis

I'm trying to find the amount of energy it would take to electrolyse sodium bromide to get 1 mole of Br2. I'm not sure how to go about calculating this figure. If anyone could help me out, I'd be very grateful.